# 2 endless looping threads in Python

Tags: python, multithreading

I have a while loop in one function listening to incoming messages from a socket connection.

```
def listenToMidiStream():
    recording = True
    global TRACK_IS_PLAYING

    thread = threading.Thread(target=loopIt)
    thread.start()

    while recording:
        stream = CLIENT_SOCK.recv(1024)
        message = json.loads(stream.decode())

        print(message)

        if message:
            MIDI_OUT.send_message(message)
            if message == [250]:
                TRACK_IS_PLAYING = True
            elif message == [252]:
                TRACK_IS_PLAYING = False
```

When the function gets called the very first time, it starts a thread where it sends out clock signals. This should stop when the Boolean is set to False.

```
def loopIt():
    global TRACK_IS_PLAYING

    while TRACK_IS_PLAYING:
        for i in range(0,8):
            MIDI_OUT.send_message(clock)

        time.sleep(interval)
```

Now the `loopIt()` gets called once. When a [250] message comes in, I can't recall the function or change the `TRACK_IS_PLAYING`. I tried several things, but can't really find how I should do this the right way.

Comment: What is `TRACK_IS_PLAYING` initialized to?

Comment: At the top of the program, set to `False`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Change your while loop in loopIt() function in this:

```
while True:
    if TRACK_IS_PLAYING:
        for i in range(0,8):
            MIDI_OUT.send_message(clock)

        time.sleep(interval)
```

Now, will sending your message only when TRACK_IS_PLAYING is set to True